# lattice : hypervolume and its associated hypersurface

Tags: geometry

Imagine I have a lattice with a point every one unit length in each direction.
I'm interested in knowing how many points I have on the border (hypersurface)
in any $D$ dimension.

- $1D$ for a length $L$, I have $L$ points.
- $2D$ for a square of side $L$, I have $4L-4$ because the corners should not
  be counted twice
- $3D$ for a cube of side $L$, I have $6L^2-12L+8$ because the edges should not
  be counted twice and the corners should not be forgotten.
- $4D$ for a tesseract, I have $8L^3-24L^2+32L-16$ for the same reasons

The coefficient I used are given for instance by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube).

Now I want two have a general formula that does the same for a hyperrectangle.

- $2D$ for a rectangle of side $L_x Ly$, I have $2(L_x+L_y)-4$
- $3D$ for edges of length $L_x,L_y,L_z$, the number of points on the surface
  is given by $2(L_xL_y +LxL_z+L_yL_z)- 4(L_x+Ly+L_z)+8$
- $4D$ for with $L_w,L_x,L_y,L_z$, I have
  $2(L_wL_xL_y+L_wL_xL_z+L_wL_yL_z+L_xL_yL_z)
    -4(L_wL_x+L_wL_y+L_wL_z+L_xL_y+L_xL_z+L_yL_z)+4(L_w+L_x+L_y+L_z)-16$

I didn't prove the formula for $4D$ but to find the coefficient I assumed that
when $L_w=L_x=L_y=L_z$ I should recover the formula for the tesseract. Is it
safe to assume that for $ND$, the formula of the hyperrectangle will be
something like:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{D-1}(-1)^i \frac{a_i}{N_i}\sum_{P_i} \prod_{\alpha} L_{P_i(\alpha)} $$

where $P_i$ is all the possible permutations of $i$ terms, $N_i$ is the number
of permutations and $a_i$ is the coefficient for the hypercube.

Is my intuition correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the formula I gave is correct.  I did some numerical test for
different dimensions and I was able to recover the correct number of points on
the ($N-1$)surface.